# EPROM data retention lifetime? Older instruments possibly due to fail?

Tags: lifetime, eprom

I have EXPENSIVE old HP instruments that are from the 1980s that work great and are certainly very good instruments, completely usable in the home lab.

Each has between 4 and 12 of the old UV type EPROMS that hold the program and other data used in the instrument.

How long do EPROMS retain data? Am I on borrowed time with these instruments?

Comment: Depends on which exact EPROM it has to read the retention specs from the datasheet. And still it tells very little, as the EPROMs may have been used in much worse or much better conditions than the rated conditions in the data sheet.

Comment: I have an old HP waveform generator. I never realized that it may contain EPROMs. If they are in sockets, you could remove them and read the data. Then you could reprogram them someday. Probably more risk removing them than waiting for them to fail someday.

Comment: Seems that Intel's design target for data retention for UVEPROM devices was ten years. An Intel document that may have addressed this was **Intel 2716 Reliability Report 19**. Good luck finding it. These chips often had a checksum programmed into them. I'd be surprised if HP did not do this, but its format might not be available.

Comment: Note that retention is usually specified at maximum ratings. It can be very long indeed at room temperature.

Answer (score 2):

EPROMs generally had a 10-year data retention guarantee.  Reliability depends primarily on how well the EPROM was programmed and storage/operating temperature.

To be safe, you should remove the EPROMs and make backup images.

One way to check the reliability of the data you read is to read the devices at 3 different voltages.  Since STM recommends a verification pass at 4.2V, I'd read at 4.2V, 5V, and 6.25V.  Check the programming algorithm for the EPROMs you're using to find the highest Vcc used and use that for the 6.25V I suggested.

If all 3 images are same, then you have a decent chance of not having any issues due to charge loss.

If you have problems comparing the image read at 4.2V, you can try increasing voltage to 4.4V.  If still unreliable, try the minimum Vcc supported by the device; either 4.5V or 4.75V.  I've had some EPROMs that wouldn't let me set Vcc much below the minimum voltage specified in the datasheet.  But, the vast majority would operate below the minimum Vcc specified in the datasheet.